# Trying to pass javascript array and int to codebehind

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, json

I am trying to pass a javascript array to a method in my code behind. The problem is, I need to pass an int to the method along with the array. When I do:

```
$.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: webMethod,
                data: JSON.stringify({ myArray : passedArray }),
```

it works. But now i can't seem to figure out how to pass the array to the code behind AND an int.
I need to pass this with the array:

```
"{'selectID' : '" + $("#ScarTattoos option:selected").val()
```

since my method paramters are:

```
public markItem getMarkNoID(int selectID, string[] person)
{
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can send a composite JSON object, like this:

```
{
    myArray: passedArray,
    selectID: $("#ScarTattoos option:selected").val()
}
```

Pass this to `JSON.Stringify` in your AJAX call and both desired objects will be sent to the server handler.

You'll have to deserialize it manually though, unless you're sending it to a web service, which usually does the deserialization itself based on parameter names (when in JSON mode).

Comment: Then make sure the fields in the JSON object have the same name as the method arguments - in your case "selectID" for the ID and "person" for the array.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure you can simply POST from a jquery ajax method to your code behind. If you were developing with MVC, yes you can POST to a controller but you appear to be using web forms. You will likely have better luck saving your JSON data to a `<asp:HiddenField />` and then posting back.

You can get the required Postback JavaScript code by invoking the `Page.ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference()` method on the server and then passing the result to your client side JavaScript code for later invokation.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest adding the array and the int to an object and stringify-ing that object.

```
var theID = $("#ScarTattoos option:selected").val();
var array = passedarray;
var PassObj = { selectID: theID, person: array};
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
var obj = {
    selectID: parseInt($("#ScarTattoos option:selected").val(), 10),
    myArray: passedArray
};
```

`$("#ScarTattoos option:selected").val()` will give you a string, so you need parseInt() to make it a number type.

Just JSON.stringify your obj and send it.